# How to initialize a firebase instance in the action creator in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

I am trying to initialize firebase using the getFirebase() in the action creator in my react application. However, I get `Cannot read property 'getFirebase'` of undefined.

I am new to firebase and I am following a tutorial online as I would like to use firebase for my project.

Please refer the action creator below:

```
export const signIn = (credentials) => (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {

    const firebase = getFirebase();

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        credentials.email,
        credentials.password
    ).then(() => {
        dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_SUCESS'});
    }).catch((error) => {
        dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_ERROR', error});
    });
}
```

Please refer the store below:

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import userReducer from '../reducers/user';
import { firebaseReducer } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default () => {

    const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        user: userReducer,
        firebase: firebaseReducer
    }),
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(
          thunk.withExtraArgument(getFirebase)
        )
    )

    // window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

    return store;
}
```

Please refer the config file below:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';


// initializing firebase
const config = {
    apiKey: theapikey,
    authDomain: "*****",
    databaseURL: "*****",
    projectId: "****",
    storageBucket: "****",
    messagingSenderId: "****"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  export default firebase;
```

Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply import firebase from the config file (where you have initialised). This `getFirebase()` seems to be unnecessary.

```
import firebase from 'firebase-config';

firebase.auth()...
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do not post your firebase project apikey and other config details here.

I believe it is a better approach to interact with the store with your application components via state management rather than tying firebase directly to store. Rather use firebase methods/features in your components and then manipulate the state as per the response from firebase.
You may follow the following steps to use firebase auth:

- export auth or other features you may need in Firebase.js rather than exporting the firebase itself as follows:

  `import * as firebase from 'firebase';
  var config = { ......... }
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  export const database = firebase.database().ref('whatever');
  export const auth = firebase.auth();
  export const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  export const twitterProvider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();`
- Then, in your Action js you may define a login function by importing auth from firebase.js and export a getUser:

  `export function getUser() {
    return dispatch => {
      dispatch({
        type: USER_STATUS,
        payload: true
      });
      auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_USER,
          payload: user
        });
        dispatch({
          type: USER_STATUS,
          payload: false
        });
      });
    };
  export function login(email, password) {
       return dispatch => auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      }`
- Then in login component js under submit call the login function:

  `this.props.login(this.state.email, this.state.password).catch(err => {
    this.setState({
      error: err
    });
  });
  function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return { user: state.user };
  }
  ..................
  export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login})(yourlogincomponent)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: nice catch for api key stuff